# Angular refreshing page after login

Tags: angular, authentication, frontend

I'm new to Angular and I want reload page after successful login and redirect to home page.

This is how my login function looks like.

```
login() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      this.user.login_user(JSON.stringify(this.loginForm.value))
      .subscribe(
        data => {  window.location.reload(); this.router.navigate(['']); },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
    } else {
      console.log('Invalid form');
    }
  }
```

This solution returns me to login page, but the login button in navigation bar successfully changed to logout button. Without that `window.location.reload()` I get redirected to home page, but I need refresh page manually to change the button from login to logout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement something like this in your user service:

```
@Injectable()
class UserService() {

    private _isLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    login_user(form: string) {
        // Call this._isLoggedIn.next(true) or this._isLoggedIn.next(false) depending on the result
    }

    get isLoggedIn() {
        return this._isLoggedIn.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Then in the component where you want to display the login/logout button, add `private userService: UserService` in the constructor, then write something like this in the template:

```
<button>{{ userService.isLoggedIn | async ? 'Logout' : 'Login' }}</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No offence, but you are missing a lot of basics in JS / Angular, as I understood from your question, you need to see some tutorials about JS.

anyway, regarding your question:

```
loggedIn: boolean;
   login() {
      if (this.loginForm.valid) {
         this.user.login_user(JSON.stringify(this.loginForm.value))
         .subscribe(
            data => {  
             this.loggedIn = true;
            //will navigate to home
            this.router.navigate(['']); 
         }, error => console.log(error));
      } else {
            console.log('Invalid form');
        }
      }
```

and for changing the button text, or any similar task you don't need ever to refresh the page using `window.location.reload();`

you may refer to a `status` variable in your component and change its value after login success, and in your template display the value according to that `status` variable

template.html

```
<button (click)="login">{{loggedIn ? 'logout' : 'login'}}</button>
```

P.S. if you want to read that value of loggedIn variable in other components, you'll have to change its type to an EventEmitter and include it in a Singelton service, push a value into it after logged success, and subscribe to it from wherever you want.